# filtering on the base of relations

Tags: rest, backend, filtering, content-management-system, strapi

let's say I have my data response in this form

```
    {
      "id": 7,
      "attributes": {
        "title": "f1 post",
        "content": "this post belongs to front end 1",
        "createdAt": "2023-10-06T07:28:19.015Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-10-06T07:52:11.827Z",
        "publishedAt": "2023-10-06T07:36:37.924Z",
        "tag": {
          "data": {
            "id": 1,
            "attributes": {
              "name": "f1",
              "createdAt": "2023-10-06T07:27:47.924Z",
              "updatedAt": "2023-10-06T07:36:22.898Z",
              "publishedAt": "2023-10-06T07:36:22.893Z"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

using this get request on this endpoint
`http://localhost:1337/api/generated-posts?populate[0]=tag`

here generated post collection has a relation with the tag.
what I want is to get all the posts that have a `tag` name `f1`
how can I perform this query in strapi?